# AS3 stack overflow?

Tags: actionscript-3

Working with Arrays. I create objects on a Class base, push them into an Array, I have 2 buttons: one adds a Child and pushes it into the Array, second one Shifts Array and removes the Child. Also a function on my mouse, if I click an object, I define it's Array number, remove the Child and... well, not sure if successful but "*delete Array[i];*" where i is target's Array number. I can see Array.length in a text field every time I do something. Second button actually does remove an object from Array, the number decreases. But deleting a specified object from the Array, as well as *Array.slice(i,1)*, doesn't reduce the Array length. So I'm afraid it may cause overflow. It's only Array, not sure, maybe **it's fine to have over a million cells in an Array?** Like if I make a game with meteor shower, meteors are removed from the screen, but the Array still has their cells. And if they appear like 30-50 per sec, it's obvious I may get memory problems in 20 minutes of running it. Well it's 60k so maybe **I shouldn't worry as only graphics take much memory?**

Still, I could use an advice on how to shift an object in a middle of an Array. Chosen one. **How do I delete it as if it never was created, same as Shift does? (it does, right?)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.splice()` will do most of the tricks. As you remove the meteor off screen, you can splice it out of the array, do like this:

```
var i:int=meteorArray.indexOf(meteorToRemove);
if (i>=0) meteorArray.splice(i,1);
```

Comment: I swear Flash is trying to kill my brain! I tried it before, it didn't work, now it does. XD Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

You should not create a new object as a good practice if you are deleting other. Try recycling, or better said 'object pools'

You should figure out the number max of elements you may use at once. create a property 'active' on each and set it to true or false instead of creating/deleting. Then you can run the update on each object and update it only if necessary

For example:

```
var meteors:Array = [];

// create 500 meteors
for ( var i:int = 0; i < 500; i++ ) {
  var meteor:Meteor = new Meteor();
  meteor.active = false;
  meteors.push(meteor);
}

// enable one meteor
meteors[0].active = true;

// in your update method:
for each (var meteor in meteors ) 
  if ( meteor.active )
    meteor.update();
```

Hope that helps.

Also you can add a helper method to get a meteor available:

```
function getMeteorAvailable():Meteor
{
  for each (var meteor in meteors ) 
      if ( !meteor.active )
        return meteor;
}
```

Comment: one has to learn to walk before he can fly. He's learned how to crawl, obviously. Although this idea is right, it's yet too advanced for him, IMHO.

Comment: Vesper, I'm a fast learner =P mika, thanks, will try that, a bit more tricky than just purge the array or make a new one, but makes sense =D

Comment: Right on @SherWood Feel free to comment on this thread if you have related questions